# How to start making a Custom View on Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I don't even know how to start it! I already looked at the source on Github but it's still hard to understand. There's a lot of things to trace.

I just need a simple view similar to what Fullcalendar already has.

I need it to look like

```
       | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday
Lunch  |        |        |         |           |          |        |
Dinner |        |        |         |           |          |        |
```

instead of `7:00AM` `7:30AM`

Or if there's another library I can use please say so.

EDIT:

I think what I need is an Agenda view without instantiating a timegrid (https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/agenda/AgendaView.js#L30)

Now the only problem is figuring out how this AgendaView works because, there are views like `agendaWeek` and `agendaDay` and it seems like it is related to this file.

I tried extending it by doing `FC.AgendaView.extend({})` but I got an infinite loading page.

Comment: this is too broad for SO. I suggest you find the bit of the source of the Week view that creates the times down the side of the calendar and then override that, but leave everything else intact, and then implement that as a custom view as per the docs. SO isn't a forum where people will generally do that sort of research on your behalf. They will, however, answer a specific question as and when you show what you've attempted and explain where you've got stuck.

Comment: @ADyson I know, I'll try reading again. But also, like what I said, I already attempted. I was really stuck. Thanks for pointing out what to look for. Maybe that will help.

Comment: if you amend the question to show what you attempted (or wait till you've had another attempt based on what I've suggested) and explain where you're stuck then you will get some more positive responses. I assume you've read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/ already?

Comment: Yes I have read that. I looked at https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/agenda/AgendaView.js because Agenda is the closest to what I need. But there's so many class. There's time grid and scroller. and in time grid it extends grid. and so on.

Comment: yes it's really not simple I suspect. But I would guess that somewhere, something will be creating an array of times of day, which can then be rendered into the HTML. It can be restricted by some of the View parameters (e.g. minTime / maxTime) so maybe tracing the passage of those values through the code will give you a clue. Running the un-minified code in a browser and stepping through it might be as a good a way as any to uncover the internals.

Comment: @ADyson OP updated. please check it out.

Comment: "an agendaview without a time grid" sounds a bit like a "basic" view. e.g. https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.3.1/demos/basic-views.html - would those be sufficient? If not, you'll have to share a lot more code than just little tiny snippets - it doesn't give sufficient info about what you've actually done in detail. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to construct a usable example. Maybe create it in JSFiddle.net so it can be worked on "live".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141981/discussion-between-jen-and-adyson).